# how to update textview in activity after a dialog is created

Tags: android

I have a fragment activity that launches a dialog whenever some stop is reached. I have some values in the `dialog` class and I need to pass it to bindviewer to update the text view in the fragment activity. But when the dialog is launched, the fragment activity is in background and I am unable to update the text view.I can also update the textview just before the dialog will be launched.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you add some code, to help us understand the problem?

Comment: You can use call back interface.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't update the view in background, just listen to the [onDismissListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener%29) and do whatever you need to do there.

Comment: I want to update the UI before or just after the dialog is created

Comment: If you want it just before:
1. Create the dialog
2. Update UI
3. Call dialog.show()